# Trying to understand why the stream is failing while it's reading the whole file

Tags: c++, ifstream

I'm trying to read a whole text-file using a simple `ifstream`.

## The code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()

{
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> DataArray;
    //std::vector<std::string> QueryArray;
    std::string filename = "c:\\helloworld.txt";
    std::ifstream myfile(filename.c_str());
    //std::ifstream qfile("queries.txt");

    if (myfile.fail()) {
        perror("c:\\helloworld.txt");
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    if (!myfile) //Always test the file open.
    {
        std::cout << "Error opening output file" << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    }
    while (std::getline(myfile, line))
    {
        DataArray.push_back(line);
    }

    /*if (!qfile) //Always test the file open.
    {
        std::cout << "Error opening output file" << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    }

    while (std::getline(qfile, line))
    {
        QueryArray.push_back(line);
    }*/

    //std::cout << QueryArray[20] << std::endl;
    std::cout << DataArray[7] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

## The result

I am getting the following result:

> Error opening output file

The text-file `my_text_file.txt` is rightly in the same directory of my program.

## Final question

It looks like it can't read `my_text_file.txt`, why? Did I do something wrong?

Also changing

```
std::ifstream myfile("c:\\my_text_file.txt");
```

to

```
std::ifstream myfile("my_text_file.txt");
```

doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  MSVS requires the text file to be in the same location as the source code files.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm rightly using Visual Studio.

Comment: Try using the absolute path, so you will know if the problem is your file or the command.

Comment: So is the text file located with the source files or is it in the location with the .exe file?

Comment: @NathanOliver just tried to put the text file `my_text_file.txt` with the path of the source files, but it doesn't work. I'm using Visual Studio 2015, x64 build.

Comment: it does not need to be in the same path as the source files, but in the same path as the executable

Comment: @tobi303 I already have tried to put the text file in the path of the executable, and in the path of the source files. But in both cases, it doesn't work

Comment: Put it where your `.sln` or `.vcxproj` is.

Comment: With my VS install the projects get saved to my documents folder.  If my soltion was named "test" the I would need to put the files in `Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Test\Test`

Comment: Just a minor quibble: `return -1;` should be `return EXIT_FAILURE;` for portability. There is no guarantee that returning `-1` from `main` will tell the OS anything meaningful. `return 0;` is okay; it's defined to do the same thing as `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I just edited it to `c:\\my_text_file.txt`. The text file is there (`C:\`). With `perror` call, as RIJIK advised me to use, I get: `c:\my_text_file.txt: No such file or directory`

Comment: @NathanOliver just edited the code, it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think your error can be caused of many different reasons.
There is a handy Error-Message-Interpreteur thing called perror([c++ reference perror](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/perror/)).
A standard way to use it(after declaring the file):

```
if(myFile.fail()){
    perror("my_text_file.txt");
    return -1;
}
```

That should give you a more detailed report on the issue, and it can tell you if the problem really is the directory of the file. Hope this helps.